# mysql.gtid_executed table on 5.7.14 empty while @@global.gtid_executed is not

Tags: mysql

Starting MySQL 5.7.6, mysql.gtid_executed is supposed to keep track of all gtids executed.

However in MySQL 5.7.14, I am seeing a scenario as below

```
    mysql> select @@global.gtid_executed;
```

`+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@global.gtid_executed                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cd5cd102-6586-0742-6f26-5b4c4c17d44d:4294967296:8589934592-8589939092 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+`

```
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * from mysql.gtid_executed;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Can this discrepancy be explained?

Comment: I think that your answer lies in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-concepts.html#replication-gtids-gtid-executed-table) along these lines `In the event of the server stopping unexpectedly, the set of GTIDs from the previous binary log is not saved in the mysql.gtid_executed table. In this case, these GTIDs are added to the table and to the set of GTIDs in the gtid_executed system variable during recovery.` after the warning on that page. Not sure though

Comment: The scenario I described is when a fresh MySQL instance has come up and has been in steady state. It started with both queries returning empty but after a while the discrepancy became visible

Comment: Then it means that some behavior in the transactions is storing the GTIDs in the variable before persists it in the table. The thing is to find this behavior in the docs. You could ask this question in http://dba.stackexchange.com , maybe the guys there can explain it.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? I see the same behavior in `5.7.33` when I bring up a new server and run some queries.

Answer (score 0):

As per the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-concepts.html#replication-gtids-gtid-executed-table)

```
If binary logging is enabled (log_bin is ON), whenever the binary log is rotated or the server is shut down, the server writes GTIDs for all transactions that were written into the previous binary log into the mysql.gtid_executed table. This situation applies on a replication source server, or a replica where binary logging is enabled.
```

I was seeing the same behavior when mysql starts up but after flushing the logs `FLUSH LOGS;` could see the GTID range in the `mysql.gtid_executed` table.